# Prevent GIF-animation from stopping, when loading other URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animated-gif

when a link is clicked, a loading animation (GIF) appears and the next url is beeing loaded via `window.location.assign()`.

the GIF-animation stops after a second - although the next site is not loaded yet. How can I make it animate until the next site appears?

I thought about loading the next site into a var and then display it via JS, but I need to have the browser's back-buttons working.

Has someone a idea how to achieve this?

Comment: that is the browser trying to erase the old and load the new contents on tab. seems out of javascript concerns.

Comment: It's caused by the browser - it will animate while the page loads from the server, but stops animating once it starts parsing.  If it's a big page, it will be noticable.

Answer (score 2):

First need to load the page via AJAX and display it manually:

```
url = '/api/html?profile=12345';
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'html'
}).always(function(response, status) {
    if ('success' !== status) {
        alert('Error loading page...');
        return;
    }

   //store state for the back and refresh button handler
   if (window.history) {
        history.replaceState({
            reloadUrl: location.href
        }, '', location.href);
        history.pushState({
            reloadHtml: response
        }, '', url);
    } //if(window.history)

    //render new page into current window
    document.open('text/html','replace');
    document.write(response);
    document.close();     
});
```

To make the **back**, **forward** and **refresh** buttons work, you must add your own handler that will display or reload the page based on saved state:

```
var allowPopState = false; //fixes popstate in Safari that fires it on every page load
$(function() { setTimeout('allowPopState = true;', 1); }); 

$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
    if (!history.state) { return; }
    if (!allowPopState && document.readyState === 'complete') {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        return;
    }

    if (history.state.reloadHtml) {
        document.open('text/html','replace');
        document.write(history.state.reloadHtml);
        document.close();
    } else if (history.state.reloadUrl) {
        if (history.state.reloadUrl === location.href) {
             location.reload();
        } else {
            location.replace(history.state.reloadUrl);
        }
    }
});
```

This will not completely keep the animation but will minimize the time when browser loads and renders the new page and will allow the animation to continue while the page is being loaded.

To make it even better, you would need to cache all resources for the next page or use lazy-loading on the next page.

---

Known bug: in desktop Firefox, this will reset page zoom (CTRL + +/- or CTRL + scroll). e.g. When you zoom current the page to 200%, the next page will be displayed in 100% zoom.

Comment: I am curious, what is `setTimeout('allowPopState = true;', 1);` supposed to do ..? And even wrapped into a `$(function() {` ...?

Comment: @davidkonrad Sorry, it got misplaced by copy&paste and should be placed BEFORE the `popstate` handler. It fixes `popstate` in Safari that fires it before document is ready. Timeout in the `$()` makes sure it gets called right after the document is ready and all its `onready` handlers were finished.